Express js cookies setting properly into browser locally but can not access the value with req.cookies
Here is my protect middleware in expess js application:
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token=req.cookies?.jwt
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      console.log(decoded)
      req.user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: decoded.email,
        },

      });
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error(`Not Authorized, Invalid Token`);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error(`Not Authorized, No Token`);
  }
});

the token is getting the value undefined though cookies is setting properly into browser after login
Here is generateToken which is generating token after every login.
 const generateToken = (res, email) => {
  console.log('email form generate',email)
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "30d",
    });
    console.log(token)
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV==="Production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV==="Production"?"None":"Strict",
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500);
    throw new Error(`Issue With Assiging JWT`);
  }
};

Here is User Controller where user profile and login user included :
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) throw new Error(`Provide Valid User Details`);
    const validUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
           email:email,
        },

    });
    if (!validUser) throw new Error(`Invalid User Details`);
    const validPassword = await compareHashPassword(password, validUser.password);
    if (validUser && validPassword) {
      generateToken(res, validUser.email);
      const data = {
        email: validUser.email,
        isAdmin: validUser.isAdmin,
      };
      res.status(200).json({
        data,
        message: `Login Successfull`,
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({message:"Invalid User Information"});
      throw new Error(`Invalid User Details`);
    }
  });
 

  const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log('user',req.user)
   try{ 
    const data = {
      email: req.user.email,
        isAdmin: req.user.isAdmin,
    };
    res.status(200).json({ data });
  }catch(error){
    res.status(401).send({message:"UnAuthorized User"})
  }
  });

here is my user Route :
// Login /api/users/signin
router.route("/signin").post(loginUser);

// Logout /api/users/logout
router.route("/logout").post(logoutUser);

//Get profile
router.get("/profile",protect, getUserProfile);

Why i can not access the cookies value with req.cookies?.jwt though i am using next js as frontend
is there any bug ?
How can i solve the problem?

req.cookies returns a string if you don't use any cookie parser middleware.

Sir, I am using cookie parser in backend . but i can't access the value of req.cookies

As you are making api requests from nextjs, you can check if cookie is being passed from nextjs app on browsers' developer console. If you are using fetch() api to make api requests use credentials: 'include' inside options. May I know how you are making api requests?

Sir  already credential are included . i am making api requests with rtk query .
